# Ordering of urls in django

Tags: python, django

I have encountered a strange issue and although I have found a solution for now I think it would be helpful to have an idea of what is causing the error. I have an app in a Django project and the urls are as follows:

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', UserProfileListView.as_view(),
        name='userprofile_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-_]+)/changepassword/$',
        password_change, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-_]+)/$',
        profile_detail,
        name='userprofile_detail'),
)
```

When i point the browser to change_password everything works fine. However is I have the urls ordered as follows:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', UserProfileListView.as_view(),
    name='userprofile_list'),
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-_]+)/$',
    profile_detail,
    name='userprofile_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-_]+)/changepassword/$',
    password_change, name='change_password'),

)
```

I get an error 404 page not found due to the fact that the view receives the username=username/changepassword and not username=username

What would be the cause of the url being interpreted in such a manner and why is it working in the first instance?

Comment: Because the first regex catches both. That's why the order is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan Klasson's comment is the answer. Just to elaborate a bit, you could have found out easily by testing your regexp:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-_]+)/$", "foobar/changepassword/")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f949c54be40>
```

FWIW the problem is with the `\w` specifier which might not do exactly what you expect:

```
>>> re.match(r"\w", "foobar/changepassword/")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f949c5a1d30>
```